# Data bindings with custom listeners on custom view

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying to bind an event on a custom view with the new Android data-binding library but run into an issue.

Here's the relevant part of my custom view:

```
public class SuperCustomView extends FrameLayout {
    private OnToggleListener mToggleListener;

    public interface OnToggleListener {
        void onToggle(boolean switchPosition);
    }

    public void setOnToggleListener(OnToggleListener listener) {
        mToggleListener = listener;
    }
    .../...
 }
```

I'm trying to use this Custom View and bind the `onToggle` event with the following:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="controller"
        type="com.xxx.BlopController"/>
</data>

<com.company.views.SuperCustomView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:onToggle="@{controller.toggleStrokeLimitation}"
       app:custom_title="Blah"
       app:custom_summary="Bloh"
       app:custom_widget="toggle"/>
```

Where `toggleStrokeLimitation` is a method on the controller:

```
public void toggleStrokeLimitation(boolean switchPosition) {
    maxStrokeEnabled.set(switchPosition);
}
```

I get this error when compiling:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:onToggle' with parameter type java.lang.Object. file:/path/to/androidapp/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_stroke.xml loc:36:35 - 36:67 ****\ data binding error ****
```

I've tried to use `android:onToggle` instead of `app:onToggle` but get the same error.

When reading the [binding events section of the doc](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#binding_events), I feel like I can wire any method off the controller to the `onToggle` event.

Does the framework wrap the `controller.toggleStrokeLimitation` methods into  a `SuperCustomView.OnToggleListener`? Any hint on the kind of magic that is behind the existing `onClick` provided by the framework?

Comment: Try to implement custom setter for onToggle attribute http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#custom_setters and make sure that controller.toggleStrokeLimitation is of OnToggleListener type

Comment: What is the type of `controller.toggleStrokeLimitation` ?. Seems like it is an `Object` and your setter expects an `OnToggleListener`

Comment: You're right, I could do that but I want to map the event to a custom method. Like explained in https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#binding_events I'll edit the question with my reasoning.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
@BindingMethods(@BindingMethod(type = SuperCustomView.class, attribute = "app:onToggle", method = "setOnToggleListener"))
public class SuperCustomView extends FrameLayout {
    private OnToggleListener mToggleListener;

    public interface OnToggleListener {
        void onToggle(boolean switchPosition);
    }

    public void setOnToggleListener(OnToggleListener listener) {
        mToggleListener = listener;
    }
    .../...
}
```

My hack to test code was:

```
public void setOnToggleListener(final OnToggleListener listener) {
    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggle = !toggle;
            listener.onToggle(toggle);
        }
    });
}
```

And on my controller object:

```
 public class MyController {

    private Context context;

    public MyController(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void toggleStrokeLimitation(boolean switchPosition) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Toggle" + switchPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

## Yeah!! it worked

Alternatively you can use xml like:

```
 <com.androidbolts.databindingsample.model.SuperCustomView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:onToggleListener="@{controller.toggleStrokeLimitation}" />
```

Now no need to add @BindingMethods annotation.

**Documentation says:**
[*"Some attributes have setters that don't match by name. For these methods, an attribute may be associated with the setter through BindingMethods annotation. This must be associated with a class and contains BindingMethod annotations, one for each renamed method. "*](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#renamed_setters)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: When i have two methods in interface it gives me the error even i add binding method at the top of custom widget class.

Comment: @AsadMukhtar use one method per Interface.... is Android way of doing things. Check the code from android here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/androidx/databinding/adapters/AdapterViewBindingAdapter.java

Comment: This really solved my problem, and work with Kotlin as well

`code
fun setOnCellClickListener(listener: OnCellClickListener) {
        setOnClickListener {
            binding.button.toggle()
            listener.handleCellClick()
        }
    }

code`

Answer (score 11):

You **may not need** `BindingMethods` for listen listeners on custom view if you define method name follow Java bean format CORRECTLY. 
Here is an example

**CustomView class**

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    ...
    private OnCustomViewListener onCustomViewListener;

    ...
    public void setOnCustomViewListener(OnCustomViewListener onCustomViewListener) {
        this.onCustomViewListener = onCustomViewListener;
    }


    ....
    public interface OnCustomViewListener {
        void onCustomViewListenerMethod(int aNumber);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<...CustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:onCustomViewListener="@{viewModel.viewModelListenerMethod}" // or use can use app:onCustomViewListener="@{viewModel::viewModelListenerMethod}"
    />
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel extends BaseObservable{

    public void viewModelListenerMethod(int aNumber){
       // handle listener here
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! What if OnCustomViewListener interface contains multiple methods?