# How to define a custom BindingMethod for a TextView?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am starting to work with the new data binding API. I want to bind on a `TextView` a custom property where I change the text and background at once. As far I understood the api there is a [`@BindingMethod`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingMethod.html) annotation for this, but the documentation is there a little weak.

I want something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:text="Important"
    tools:background="@drawable/bg_badge_important"
    tools:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    custom:badge="@{item.badge}"/>
```

Where this `item.badge` is a string like important or notice. For i18n I cannot use this string directly but this will help me to choose the right text and the right background image.

Can you give me a small example or a reference how to use this attribute? I just found [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32715186/995926) on Stack Overflow, but this does not answer my question.

Comment: You wrote "for the hole time I saved" in your candidate speech. Instead of "whole time".

Comment: Oh no, not again. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a public static method on your codebase and annotate with @BindingAdapter.

Here is an example for fonts:

https://plus.google.com/+LisaWrayZeitouni/posts/LTr5tX5M9mb

Edit by rekire I ended in using this code:

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:badge"})
public static void setBadge(TextView textView, String value) {
    switch(value) {
        case "email":
            textView.setText(R.string.badge_email);
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_badge_email);
            break;
        // other cases
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Boy is the world small, I was in her talk in London, where she show that code too. I'll check that tomorrow.

Comment: I added the code I'm using now. Thank you for pointing out that google+ posting!